# How to run django test on google cloud platform

Tags: python, django, testing, google-cloud-platform

i'm deploying my app on Google Cloud platform. Every thing seems to be set up correctly but when i try to launch test, i get this error :

```
======================================================================
ERROR: purbeurre.core (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: purbeurre.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 462, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'purbeurre.core'
```

Is there a special setting to have all my test modules loaded ?

i did check locally and it's working on my dev environnement

Answer (score 1):

It appear that i have an **init**.py file at root level of my project and it's messing up with unittest. 
After deleting this **init**.py file the test is launched properly